# Background video doesn't work on hover in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video

I'm trying to accomplish background video playing with sound when I hover a link. Actually it works fine in all browsers except Chrome. What's going on in Chrome is I see the first frame of my video when
I hover a link and nothing more. Reloading the page doesn't solve the problem. But clicking on logo to refresh the page do solve the problem. When I add "muted" to video tag it also works fine. I read that Chrome blocks video and audio autoplay by default (I have 66.0.3359.181 Version of Chrome).

So is there any solution to play background video with sound in Chrome on first entrance?

You can check out the website example here:

http://s90685xj.beget.tech/

The code I'm using:

```js
var viewport = document.getElementsByClassName('fade')[0]
var video = document.getElementById('video')
viewport.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  video.play()
}, false);
viewport.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  video.pause()
}, false);
document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  this.currentTime = 24;
}, false);
```

```html
<a href="#" class="fade film">New York<span><video id="video" class="video-background"><source src="http://s90685xj.beget.tech/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Hernandos-Hideaway-Broadway-Dreams-NYC-Showcase-2016.mp4"></source></video></span></a>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I'd advise against having sound on enter it really does piss off users

Comment: also seems to be working fine on chrome for me